# Should I set up Passport.js or similar for authentication if my site will only have 2 or 3 administrators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, authentication, express

Pardon me if this question is inappropriate here.

I am working on my first big Node.js/Express web app. I'm making something to maintain a database and visualize data for an organization. This app is mostly a data visualizer, but I need to make an interface to maintain the data for the admins. There will only ever be a handful of them at most and data will be edited about once a year.

I've never worked with a web app framework ever before and was having a bit of trouble trying to set up Passport.js for authentication. I can probably still set it up if I try, but is it worth the effort? Is there another, even simpler way I can authenticate in this type of a scenario?

Would it be okay to hardcode username and password values and/or only temporarily open the database editing page?

Answer (score 0):

I find that passport.js has [local authentication](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local) and it's fairly simple to use. For that matter, I would actual suggest it, the work you put in to set it up far outweighs what you might have to change later on.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest solution may be Stormpath.  Here's the link on how it do it with [Express in under 15 minutes](https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app/).

It will offload all the authentication work for you (secure password storage, password reset, authentication, groups & roles, etc)  with just a little bit of configuration on your end.

They've got a free tier that should be enough for what you're describing.

*Full Disclosure - I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com/)*